# ADFS server is also Remote Desktop server - constant prompts HTTP 401 error

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, iis-7.5, remote-desktop-services, adfs

Our Remote Desktop server (2008 R2) is also hosting the IIS ADFS site. ADFS works beautifully for internal and external clients.

Except, if I try to connect with a service that uses ADFS **from the Remote Desktop session host server that also hosts IIS.**

When I do, transparent authentication does not work, and instead I get continual username/password prompts followed eventually by the obligatory IIS error:

```
Server Error in Application "DEFAULT WEB SITE/ADFS/LS"

Internet Information Services 7.5

Error Summary

HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

What could this be?

Bear in mind that I have verified the authentication settings are set to default on the `Default Website/adfs` and `Default Website/adfs/ls` folders respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by specifying the host name of the ADFS server in the `BackConnectionHostNames` key, as per method 1 here, then running `iisreset`.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/896861